# Lotus Notes document to PDF

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I need some help since I do not know where to start. Ideally, I would like to have a button that can convert my Lotus Notes document to a PDF file, then it will open up a new email then take the email address in that document to the "To" filed. At this point we use CutePDF writer to create the PDF file. I break down the process like the one below:

1. Print a document
2. User choose CutePDFwriter
3. Save the pdf file
4. Compose a new email with the email address that is on the Notes document placed on the 'To' field

Can anyone help me starting on this?

Comment: If you go the www.openNTF.org web site and search for "PDF", you will find several open source projects that deal with creating PDF files from Notes data.  The project "PDF IT" deals with creating PDF files from views.  The project "SimplePDF" deals with data from documents.

Comment: If you can't find any other approach that works, you could write a Java agent that uses one of the Java PDF libraries (e.g. iText) to create the PDF files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer from Domino Designer help file. Use the code below to open up mail file

```
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument

Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim item As NotesItem
Set doc = uidoc.Document
Set item = doc.GetFirstItem("QSContactEMail")

Set uidoc = workspace.ComposeDocument _
(mailserver$, mailfile$, "Memo")
Call uidoc.FieldAppendText("EnterSendTo", "Test")
```

For the printing I just call the print function and let the user choose CutePDF writer

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to let the user select cutepdf as the printer, you should be able to get away with using @Commands in a button from the either the document or a view containing the documents (Check the notes designer help).

The only issue I can see is that the user will be able to change the path that cutepdf prints to, so you will have to make the user find the attachment again (but you will be able to automate the attachment dialog coming up).

Comment: I am trying to use this code but it will not open my mail file and displayed a new email window:
  Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
  Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
  Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
  Call uidoc.Print

  Dim db As New NotesDatabase( "", "")
  Call db.OpenMail
 
  Dim doc As NotesDocument
  Set doc = db.CreateDocument